# Recovering Deleted SQLite Records on Disk

Tags: data-recovery, sqlite

I'm trying to access the raw screentime data that Android tracks - located in `/data/data/com.google.android.apps.wellbeing/databases/app_usage` on my OnePlus 7 Pro.

My problem is that the database only goes back a month's worth of records - presumably old records are deleted regularly to conserve space.

I considered doing a full disk dump and attempting some type of data recovery, but I'm unsure of exactly what to do - given that it isn't full files that are deleted, just SQLite records, I don't know if conventional data recovery tools would easily find anything.

I also tried running [undark](https://github.com/witwall/undark) on a copy of the database to see if I could get anything out of it, but as I suspected nothing new was found.

Are there any known methods or tools for recovering the deleted SQL records (assuming they haven't been overwritten) from disk, preferably without doing a full-disk dump?

I can provide more information if necessary.

Comment: The SQLite DB file is being updated a scores of times daily (by adding new records and deleting old ones). Filesystem cannot provide any information when a file with same name is overwritten on the same location. So if the DB file itself doesn't have the deleted records (what `undark` tries to recover), I don't think it would be possible to recover the deleted entries by recovering the DB file.

Comment: Ah, that's what I feared. Thank you for confirming it.